# Xcode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain error

Tags: ios, keychain

I've finished the app and am trying to upload it onto a device for testing. I've stumbled upon this error on the organizer window, but the thing is I already have the certificate that the provision file is created based on (using the apple portal guide) and also the private key that goes with it.

There is a triangle in the key chain access, both under the "certificate" section and the "key" section of login.

Also I've checked and am building the app under "debugging", not "release", so Xcode 4 should be looking for the developer certificate, not the distribution one, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem yesterday. I solved deleting the initial ones Apple had me install and submitting for a new one. Go to the iOS Provisioning Portal and click on Certificates on the side. There's a [How-To tab](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action) which gives a step by step process of doing it right. After I followed the instructions, I was able to sign my app under my Developer provision profile.

Also, you need the Apple's WWDR intermediate certificate installed. The download for that is under the Certificate section under any tab.

Comment: Yes i do have the WWDR certificate installed, just wondering is there a way to do this without revoking? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a Technical Note that describes the process of deleting your existing development certificate and obtaining a new one here:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Deleting expired/revoked developer certificates from my Keychain did the trick!